# Reshaping data into long forma

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

I have two large data frames, the sample below shows what they look like:

```
Name<-c("ST01","ST02","ST03")
B1<-c(0.01,0.003,0.04)
B2<-c(0.02,0.002,0.02)
B3<-c(0.04,0.008,0.06)
B4<-c(0.08,0.009,0.08)
B5<-c(0.09,0.004,0.05)

df1<-data.frame(Name,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
 
 Name    A1    A2    A3    A4   A5
1 ST01 0.020 0.040 0.050 0.060 0.08
2 ST02 0.036 0.034 0.054 0.034 0.24
3 ST03 0.140 0.320 0.560 0.780 0.59

Name<-c("ST01","ST02","ST03")
A1<-c(0.02,0.036,0.14)
A2<-c(0.04,0.034,0.32)
A3<-c(0.05,0.054,0.56)
A4<-c(0.06,0.034,0.78)
A5<-c(0.08,0.24,0.59)

df2<-data.frame(Name,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)

 Name    B1    B2    B3    B4    B5
1 ST01 0.010 0.020 0.040 0.080 0.090
2 ST02 0.003 0.002 0.008 0.009 0.004
3 ST03 0.040 0.020 0.060 0.080 0.050
```

I would like to reshape them so that I can use ggplot to plot all the As against Bs and then plot As against Bs for each value, my desired output would be something like this:

```
  Name Value     A     B
1  ST01     1 0.020 0.010
2  ST01     2 0.040 0.020
3  ST01     3 0.050 0.040
4  ST01     4 0.060 0.080
5  ST01     5 0.080 0.090
6  STO2     1 0.036 0.003
7  STO2     2 0.034 0.002
8  STO2     3 0.054 0.008
9  STO2     4 0.034 0.009
10 STO2     5 0.240 0.004
11 ST03     1 0.140 0.040
12 ST03     2 0.320 0.020
13 ST03     3 0.560 0.060
14 ST03     4 0.780 0.080
15 ST03     5 0.590 0.050
>
```

I am new to R so not quite if this can be done, or if there is a more appropriate way to shape the data in order to plot. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first merge your datasets using a `left_join` then reshape to long  by utilizing the `names_pattern` argument of `pivot_longer` and the special `".value"`. For the `names_pattern` argument I use the regex `"(.)(.)"` to split the column names into two one character strings, e.g. `"A1"` is split in to `"A"` and `"1"` where the first part (`"A"`) gives the name of the value column and the second part (`"1"`) is stored as category in the name column (`"Value"`):

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

left_join(df2, df1, by = "Name") |>
  pivot_longer(-Name, names_to = c(".value", "Value"), names_pattern = "(.)(.)")
#> # A tibble: 15 × 4
#>    Name  Value     A     B
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 ST01  1     0.02  0.01 
#>  2 ST01  2     0.04  0.02 
#>  3 ST01  3     0.05  0.04 
#>  4 ST01  4     0.06  0.08 
#>  5 ST01  5     0.08  0.09 
#>  6 ST02  1     0.036 0.003
#>  7 ST02  2     0.034 0.002
#>  8 ST02  3     0.054 0.008
#>  9 ST02  4     0.034 0.009
#> 10 ST02  5     0.24  0.004
#> 11 ST03  1     0.14  0.04 
#> 12 ST03  2     0.32  0.02 
#> 13 ST03  3     0.56  0.06 
#> 14 ST03  4     0.78  0.08 
#> 15 ST03  5     0.59  0.05
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was not aware that the col names could be split into two character strings.